# Value that comes from an @input field is not being displayed

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm trying to create a dynamic reactive form, but the value is not being displayed

```html
<div *ngFor="let deliveryAcross of (deliveriesAcross | async)!; let i = index;">
  <app-delivery-across
    [index]="i"
    [deliveryAcross]="deliveryAcross"
  ></app-delivery-across>
  {{ deliveryAcross | json }}
</div>
```

deliveryacross.component.ts

```
  @Input("deliveryAcross") deliveryAcross: IDeliverAcross;

  minFormControl: FormControl;
  errorStateMatcher: NextErrorStateMatcher;
  constructor(private change: ChangeDetectorRef, private store: Store) {
    this.deliveryAcross = {
      iso: "",
      min: 1,
      max: 2,
      shippingCents: 0,
      shippingEuros: 0,
    };

    this.minFormControl = new FormControl("", [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.min(1),
    ]);
    this.errorStateMatcher = new NextErrorStateMatcher();
  }
```

I can't use `ngModel` because it would cause readonly errors that's why I choose to use value instead, but my value is not being displayed rather the input refreshes back to empty

```html
<mat-form-field
  class="full-width"
  [@transformRightLeftStateTrigger]="stateDown | async"
>
  <input
    matInput
    [formControl]="minFormControl"
    [errorStateMatcher]="errorStateMatcher"
    placeholder="Minimaal"
    appDeliveryAcross
    [value]="deliveryAcross.min"
    autocomplete="off"
    [key]="'min'"
    [component]="'delivery-across'"
    type="number"
  />
</mat-form-field>
```

Why the value that comes from `deliveryAcross.min` is not displayed in input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you're using `value` side by side with `formControl` as a source of value for the input, so the initial value of `formControl` overrides the `value` one.

You can try to use one source such as `formControl`, then use `ngOnChanges` to get the changes of `this.deliveryAcross` input, so you can write it again to the `formControl`.

Try the following:

```js
ngOnInit() {
  // Move this part to the `ngOnInit` so you can read the value of `this.deliveryAcross` input,
  // and set it as initial value of the form-control.
  this.minFormControl = new FormControl(this.deliveryAcross?.min, [
    Validators.required,
    Validators.min(1)
  ]);
}

// implement `OnChanges` interface to get the input changes.
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
  if(changes.deliveryAcross) {
    this.minFormControl.setValue(this.deliveryAcross?.min);
  }
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field
  class="full-width"
  [@transformRightLeftStateTrigger]="stateDown | async"
>
  <input
    matInput
    [formControl]="minFormControl"
    [errorStateMatcher]="errorStateMatcher"
    placeholder="Minimaal"
    appDeliveryAcross
    autocomplete="off"
    [key]="'min'"
    [component]="'delivery-across'"
    type="number"
  />
</mat-form-field>
```